# mraid undefined

Tags: javascript, mraid

I've been trying to create an mraid compliant ad, but haven't gotten very far. According to the official documentation, which can be found at [this link](http://www.iab.net/media/file/IAB_MRAID_v2_FINAL.pdf), the addition of a simple

`<script src='mraid.js'></script>`

should be sufficient. This, however, doesn't seem to be the case. I copied the following example code to test the existence of the mraid object, but it just stays undefined. The precise FireBug error is:

> ReferenceError: mraid is not defined

I'm trying to execute the following (very simple) code:

```
if(mraid.getState() !='ready'){
console.log("MRAID NOT READY");}
```

Does anyone have any experience with this problem?

Comment: Your code is wrong, you expect mraig.getState to return 'ready', but this state do not exist. It's a common error on many MRAID sample codes, indeed when mraid is ready, the mraid.getState return 'default'.

Comment: Thanks for your comment! :) It isn't the problem here, as John Cappiello mentioned already, but could definitely have been a problem later on :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, it's not quite as simple as that, and the spec isn't entirely clear.

mraid.js is injected by whatever ad platform your being flighted from.

It looks something like this:

App -> Ad SDK -> MRAID Ad

The Ad SDK instantiates a UIWebView and injects mraid.js to be available.  Then your script tag above finds it, loads it, and everything else resolves itself from there.

Your options are either:

1. make your own mraid.js for testing purposes that has enough of the spec to be handy /testing
2. spin up a mobile ad server SDK that does the above for you, and then just test against that
3. checkout http://webtester.mraid.org which will let you avoid some of the above

2 is the most precise.  1 & 3 get you far, but nothing compares to the real thing in app with an actual ad server's sdk handling things.

Comment: Thanks! The documentation is very unclear, your explanation is considerably more informative!

Comment: What would a test mraid.js look like? I found a mock used by admob (Google), but this doesn't seem to work.

Comment: it would have to implement the mraid object, and all events, listeners, and methods, required by the spec, or at least the subset you're using.  Look at the code buried in webtester which is available as a full download here http://code.google.com/p/mraid-web-tester/